# Why is my Code Printing the same Last Name?

Tags: python

The Code Below I wrote takes input from a sample file which contains First and Last names. Then it converts those names to sample emails. For some reason the Script keeps printing the same Last name over and over.

namess.txt looks like this:
firstname,lastname

CODE:

```
import os, re, time, getpass, linecache

Original = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop','namess.txt')
File = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop','output.txt')
badNames = []
Names = []

def RemCommas():
    outfile = open(os.path.join('C:\\', 'Users', getpass.getuser(), 'Desktop','output.txt'),'w')
    Filedata = open(Original).read()
    outfile.write(re.sub(',', ' ', Filedata))
    outfile.close()

def ClassNum():
    count = 6
    Year = int(time.strftime('%Y'))
    Class = str((Year - 2013) + 6)
    return Class

def ReadStoreFile():
    i = 0
    OpenFile = open(File) 
    LenFile = len(OpenFile.readlines())
    while i < LenFile:
        i += 1
        badNames.append(linecache.getline(File, i))

def CleanNames():
    i = 0
    while i < len(badNames):
        cleaned = badNames[i].rstrip()
        Names.append(cleaned)
        i += 1

def NamePrint():
    Interns = 'makchessclub.org'
    arrayname = []
    i = 0
    j = 0
    m = 0

    while m < len(Names): 
        Name = Names[m]
        Name = Name.lower()
        InternName = Name[0] + Name[1]
        #------------Checking for space and first name--
        while i < len(Name):
            if Name[i] == ' ':
                i = Name.index(' ')
                break;   
            i += 1
        #---------------adding last name in an array----
        Namelen = len(Name) - (i+1)
        while j < Namelen:
            arrayname.append(Name[i+1])
            j += 1
            i += 1
        #---------------Final Name Print----------------
        Lastname = ''.join(arrayname)
        #print arrayname
        #Lastname = Lastname.strip(' ')
        #print InternName + Lastname + ClassNum() + Interns
        file = open('C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\emails.txt', 'a')
        file.write(InternName + Lastname + ClassNum() + Interns + '\n')
        file.close()
        m += 1

RemCommas()
ReadStoreFile()
CleanNames()
NamePrint()

print ''
os.system('pause')
```

Comment: Suggestion: rather than `os.path.join('C:\\', 'Users', getpass.getuser(), 'Desktop', 'something.txt')`, use `os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop', 'something.txt')`. It will then work on systems other than Windows as long as there's a `Desktop` folder in the user's home directory.

Comment: changed it. thanks icktoofay: learned something new :)

Comment: I'm not sure how you got this program to run given the line `file = open('C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\emails.txt', 'a')` unless your system happens to have a user named `username`. Also, it's wise to avoid variable names like `file` since it's likely a keyword in the language.

Comment: You shouldn't really need to iterate through strings in python as most of the tools you need are already provided.

To get a 'last name':

    `name[name.find(' ')+1:]`

Comment: @mbratch : good comment. I thought it wise not to give out my username.

Comment: Ah. No problem. But I would have expected it to determine the path programmatically, like you had done for `Original` and `File`. Also note that some of the `print` statement syntax is wrong. For example, `print ''` should be `print ('')`. So I wasn't sure how you got the program to run.

Comment: my apologies: i was trying to write it fast :)

Comment: @mbratch: In Python 2, `print` is a statement. In Python 3, `print` is a function. As such, the program is valid in Python 2.

Comment: @icktoofay, thanks! I wasn't aware of that. To Ahmed, *my* apologies to *you*.

Comment: Sanjay Manohar: ur code is nice and works, but can u explain what is +1 for? if anyone else can explain then that would be great to :)

Comment: The +1 is because you need to go one more character after the found space (' ') to get to the name. The find locates the space, then the +1 takes you to the first non-space after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the last name doesn't change is because you are not resetting `arrayname` in your loop. You keep appending names to it, and the program picks the first one. So you should put your `arrayname = []` after the `while m < len(Names):`

Comment: hmm this works for the first name, the rest of them dont even get the last name printed. arrayname ends up empty.

Comment: got this answer working with this code to but a shout out to  Sanjay Manohar, his code: name[name.find(' ')+1:] made my code more efficient and it worked.

Comment: Yes, sorry Ahmed, good catch. My comment on arrayname was really more aimed at indicating that it was only setup once for the entire loop. I apologize I did not think through what the best place was for it. Peter gave a fuller, more efficient algorithm. My objective was primarily to indicate an answer to your direct question as to why the name wasn't coming out correctly based upon your current implementation.

Comment: mbratch I appreciate our answer more then mine because it was aimed at solving my code, rather then rearrange it. Thanks man :)

Answer (score 2):

I guess this what you are trying to do:

```
import os
import re
import time

def create_mails(input_path, output_path, year, addr):
    with open(input_path, 'r') as data:
        mail = re.sub(r'(\w+)\s*,\s*(\w+)\n?', r'\1\g<2>%s%s\n' % (year, addr), data.read())
    with open(output_path, 'w') as output:
        output.write(mail.lower())
    print 'Mail addresses generated and saved to', output_path
```

Demo:

```
create_mails(
    os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop', 'namess.txt'),
    os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop', 'output.txt'),
    str(int(time.strftime('%Y')) - 2013 + 6),
    '@makchessclub.org'
)
```

If `namess.txt` is something like this:

```
First, Last
John,Doe
Spam, Ham
Cabbage, egg
```

Then `output.txt` is going to be like this:

```
firstlast6@makchessclub.org
johndoe6@makchessclub.org
spamham6@makchessclub.org
cabbageegg6@makchessclub.org
```

Comment: @Ahmed If you found ot useful, please vote up! (anyway: it's not that difficult, try to understand it step by step!)